# Deprecated setLineBreakMode Warning

Tags: xcode, uibutton

I am getting a warning of deprecated method when using

```
[buttonLeft setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Is there any other substitute of this method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try

```
[buttonLeft.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Answer (score 10):

For `UILabel`, the appropriate constant is now `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` (instead of `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`):

```
titleLabel.lineBreakMode =  NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Answer (score 1):

can try the the following. it's bit long but i think it will work:

// we only want to add our custom label once; only 1st pass shall return nil
    UILabel  *titleLabel = (UILabel*)[self viewWithTag:TITLE_LABEL_TAG];

```
if (!titleLabel) 
{
    // no custom label found (1st pass), we will be creating & adding it as subview
    titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:titleRect];
    [titleLabel setTag:TITLE_LABEL_TAG];

    // make it multi-line
    [titleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [titleLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    // title appearance setup; be at will to modify
    [titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [titleLabel setFont:[self font]];
    [titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
    [titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

    [self addSubview:titleLabel];
    [titleLabel release];
}

// finally, put our label in original title view's state
[titleLabel setText:title];
[titleLabel setTextColor:titleColor];
[titleLabel setShadowColor:titleShadowColor];

// and return empty rect so that the original title view is hidden
return CGRectZero;
```

}

Comment: UIButton already has customizable titleLabel inside it, so you don't need to create another one

Answer (score 0):

Just check out and replace these enums.

In the previos of ios6 was:-
 [image]

From IOS 6 it is:-

[image]